# How to copy folder from remote server (digital Ocean) to local computer

Tags: digital-ocean, scp

I am trying to copy a folder from my digital Ocean server to my computer.
I have successfully connected as root to my server and I have the ssh Public key setup

I use command `root@my-server_ip to` connect successfully.

When I try to copy a file like

```
scp -r root@my-server_ip:/file/path/ /where/to/put
```

I get this error `Permission denied (publickey).`

I can't figure out what the heck is the issue

Answer (score 1):

`Permission denied` occurs when the server is not able to validate the incoming connection. You need to provide the path to your identity file (ssh key) explicitly when making a request through scp.

Something like this:

`scp -i <path_to_identity_file> -r root@my-server_ip:/file/path/ /where/to/put`